# fill-paragraph for Google style docstrings

Tags: python, formatting, fill-paragraph, doc-strings

When editing an existing docstring in [Google style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#s3.8.1-comments-in-doc-strings) you need to call a function like `fill-paragraph` to cut the long lines while preserving the proper indentation. However `fill-paragraph` will not work under `Returns:` and even less so under `Args:` with the individual arguments. E.g.,

```
    Returns:
        This function returns the list of dates in reverse order.
```

is transformed in

```
    Returns: This function returns the list of dates in reverse order.
```

Under `Args:`, all arguments are mixed together:

```
    Args:
        a: A sequence of strings representing the key of each table row to
          fetch. String keys will be UTF-8 encoded.
        b: Second argument.
```

is transformed in

```
    Args: a: A sequence of strings representing the key of each table row to
    fetch.  String keys will be UTF-8 encoded.  b: Second argument.
```

For Epydoc style, there is the nice minor mode [python-docstring-mode](https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode) that replaces `fill-paragraph` with `python-docstring-fill`. That works perfectly.

Is there a similar minor mode for Google style docstrings? Or an option based on lsp-mode/eglot or anything else? Note that I do not want to generate the docstrings but to "fill"/reformat it so that when editing it, I can reformat it automatically, typically by hitting `M-q`. Even reformatting just the current paragraph or argument would be nice (instead of the entire docstring).

Comment: Please don't post the same question on emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: All right. Here is the selected remaining question.

Comment: Thx............